# adding hits in short url script

Tags: php, mysql, url, short, hit

i have a short url script and i want to add link hit functionality to it.

when someone visits a link generated from the script then the hits get updated in the database.

i made a mysql table with the following fields:

```
id, shortened_url, url, timestamp, hits.


  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `shortened_url` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @charmaine All your questions suck. Quit asking for help on advanced web programming before you have even learned the basics. You can't even add an echo statement as requested below! You can not simply cut and paste your way into sophisticated programming. You are wasting people's time when they try to help a person they think can be helped.

Comment: and what is your problem? move over DG. you may be some hotshot php pro but i really want to learn. its you who suck.

Comment: @charmaine Wanting to learn is good, but I'm telling you honestly that you are taking the wrong approach. Trying to track hits from the use of a bookmarklet before you even know how to use `echo` is learning how to program ass-backwards. I personally don't care if you learn the wrong way or the right way, but you are wasting people's time by trying to learn the wrong way through this site. Start with some basic tutorials and work your way up to a reasonable level first. (And also you are only hurting yourself. In the future you'll look back and think, "Wow, DG wasn't a lying.)

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess if you really want it to get updated in the database, rather than using a solution like google apps you can do the following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a .scriptGenerated").bind('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var postUrl = 'some page on your site to post to';

       var shortUrl = $(this).attr('shorturl');   ///replace short url with whatever that means
       var url = $(this).attr('href');
       var time = new Date();

       var data = {"shorturl":shorturl, "url" : url, "time" : time};

       $.post({null, postUrl, data, success:function(result){window.location = url;}});
   });
});
```

This has some bugs in it I think but the idea is it stops the anchor, which has a "scriptGenerated" class, from executing, pulls data from it (the anchor DOM elements), and posts it to some page in your application where you can take in the data from the POST. If it is successful it will then redirect to the appropriate page. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are looking to do though.

Comment: I think the issue is not with redirecting arbitrary links on a page, but implementing the `postURL` page.

Answer (score 0):

On your short-URL redirect page, execute the following queries:

```
SELECT url from [tablename] WHERE shortened_url=[short_url]
UPDATE [table_name] SET hits=hits+1 WHERE shortened_url=[short_url]

#redirect to url retrieved from first query
```

If you so desire, you can use the `shortened_url` as the unique identifier for the table (since, by definition, each short URL needs to be unique). No need for the numeric `id` in this case.

---

Try this:

```
$shortened_url = mysql_real_escape_string($shortened_url);

mysql_query("UPDATE [tablename] SET hits=hits+1 WHERE
    shortened_url='$shortened_url'");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM [tablename] WHERE
    shortened_url='$shortened_url' LIMIT 1", $db);
echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
if (!empty($row)) { 
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: " . $row[2]);
}
```

Comment: still no work. class below: [$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `" . $db_server . "`.`tablename` WHERE `shortened_url`='" . mysql_escape_string($shortened_url) . "' LIMIT 1", $db);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
if (!empty($row))
 {
 header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
 header("Location: " . $row[2] . "");
 }
]

Comment: @charmaine, try the updated code. You are using the actual table name, correct?

Comment: what's the error? add `echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n";` after your last query.

Comment: thats too much for me im afraid. im a noob after all. thanks for the help btw. great learning.

Comment: @charmaine, don't give up! All that does is output the error you're running into.

Comment: @charmaine, see updated post. you should see the error outputted to your page.

Comment: nope still no good. maybe php is not a girl thing and i should better skip it now :(     thanks for your help though. c ya!